# React Native Stateless Function Not Rendering When Imported

Tags: function, react-native, rendering, stateless

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { ExpandableTab } from "./components/ExpandableTab";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text>1 2 1 2... mic check</Text>
      <ExpandableTab />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

**ExpandableTab.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

export default function ExpandableTab() {
  return <Text>yeo dawg</Text>;
}
```

Running app on iOS Simulator and I see **1 2 1 2... mic check** in the center of the screen, but nothing else.

Comment: import ExpandableTab from './components/ExpandableTab'

Comment: You don’t need to add curly braces on default export

Comment: As @akshaylalwani said you have to import `ExpandableTab` like this : `import 
 ExpandableTab  from "./components/ExpandableTab";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you are importing `ExpandableTab`

```
import ExpandableTab from "./components/ExpandableTab";
```

Comment: that's it! Thank you!